# поиск xpath по двум условиям

Tags: html, selenium, xpath

Всем привет. 
Не получается найти значение элементов

`<div class="outcomeContent___1WRV5">1.94</div>`

`<div class="outcomeContent___1WRV5">2.15</div>`

Знаю, что нужно искать в div `<div class="marketsGroup___1F_9w">` т.к. он содержит условие в другом div

`<div class="marketsGroupHeader__content___1VVDt">Кто забьёт 2-ой гол?</div>`

я дошел до этих divoв:

```
//div[contains(@class, 'event')]/div[contains(@class, 'marketsGroup')]
```

как теперь использовать два условия, чтобы найти необходимое мне значение?

Заранее спасибо за потраченное на меня время!

привожу пример HTML, но не уверен насчет правильного отображения форматировая.
Прилагаю скриншот [image: скриншот]

```
<div class="marketsGroup___1F_9w">
<div class="marketsGroup___1F_9w">
<div class="marketsGroupHeader___2FhRe">
   <div class="marketsGroupHeader__content___1VVDt">Кто забьёт 2-ой гол?</div>
   <svg class="marketsGroupHeader__right___Vz0to" fill="currentColor" preserveAspectRatio="xMidYMid meet" height="1em" width="1em" viewBox="0 0 24 24" style="vertical-align: middle;">
</div>
<div class="marketsGroup__content___3TpYG" style="height: auto;">
<div class="ReactCollapse--content">
<div>
   <div class="marketsGroupTile___2Ti1X">
      <div class="marketsGroupTile___2Ti1X row___1NaHy">
         <div class="marketsGroupTile___2Ti1X col___EZWtV">
            <div class="outcome___Hl8Yn withName___kH2rz marketsGroup__outcome___1Rnm_">
               <div class="outcomeName___qHZG1">Тальерес-де-Кордоба</div>
               <div class="outcomeContent___1WRV5">1.90</div>
            </div>
         </div>
         <div class="marketsGroupTile___2Ti1X col___EZWtV">
            <div class="marketsGroupTile___2Ti1X col___EZWtV">
               <div class="outcome___Hl8Yn withName___kH2rz marketsGroup__outcome___1Rnm_">
                  <div class="outcomeName___qHZG1">Бока Хуниорс</div>
                  <div class="outcomeContent___1WRV5">2.40</div>
               </div>
            </div>
         </div>
      </div>
      <div>
      </div>
   </div>
</div>
<div class="marketsGroup___1F_9w">
<div class="marketsGroup___1F_9w">
```

Comment: `.//*[@id='react-root']/div/div[2]/div/div[1]/div/div[1]/div//div[contains(text(), 'Кто забьёт 2-ой гол?')]` надо вернуться на два уровня выше и искать там

Answer (score 0):

РЕШЕНО!  .//*[@id='react-root']/div/div[2]/div/div[1]/div/div[1]/div//div[contains(text(), 'Кто забьёт 2-ой гол?')]/ancestor-or-self::div[3]